# Downloading files using Python-requests

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-requests

I wrote a Python script to download files using multiple (source) IP addresses -- kindly suggest any improvements.

```
import cgi
import os
import posixpath
import Queue
import threading
import urllib
import urlparse
import random
import re
import shutil
import time

import requests
import requests_toolbelt

def get_IPs():
    """Returns all available IP addresses in a list."""
    # TODO: Windows only. Other options?
    out = []
    for i in os.popen('ipconfig'):
        i = i.strip()
        if i.startswith('IP'):
            out.append(i.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1])

    return out

def get_info(url):
    """Returns name and size of file to be downloaded."""
    try:
        resp = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
        name = cgi.parse_header(resp.headers['content-disposition'])[1]['filename']
    except KeyError:
        path = urlparse.urlsplit(url).path
        name = posixpath.basename(path)
    name = urllib.unquote_plus(name)
    size = int(resp.headers['content-length'])
    return name, size

def worker(url, session, ud, part, size):
    """Downloads a part of the file specified by 'part' parameter."""
    # TODO: optimal tries, timeout?
    headers = {'range': 'bytes=%s-%s' % (
        part*CHUNK_SIZE, min(size, (part + 1)*CHUNK_SIZE - 1))}
    for _ in xrange(MAX_RETRIES):
        try:
            data = session.get(url, timeout=(2, 7), headers=headers).content
            with open('%s/%04d' % (ud, part), 'wb') as udw:
                udw.write(data)
            break
        except:
            pass
    else:
        worker(url, sessions_queue.get(), ud, part, size)

    sessions_queue.put(session)

def summary(name, size, elapsed):
    """Prints summary of the download after it is completed."""
    print (
        '--\n'
        '%s download completed.\n'
        'Time elapsed: %.2fs\n'
        'Average download speed: %.2f MB/s\n'
        '--' % (name, elapsed, size/elapsed/2**20))

def download(url):
    """Downloads the file pointed to by 'url' parameter."""
    start = time.clock()
    name, size = get_info(url)
    # random id of length 20
    ud = '%0x' % random.getrandbits(80)
    os.mkdir(ud)
    threads = []
    for i in xrange(size/CHUNK_SIZE + (size%CHUNK_SIZE != 0)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(url, sessions_queue.get(), ud, i, size))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    # characters \/:*?"<>| not allowed in filenames in Windows
    name = re.sub(r'[\\/:*?"<>|]', '_', name)
    # TODO: check if a file is already present with same name
    out = open(name, 'ab')
    for i, t in enumerate(threads):
        t.join()
        out.write(open('%s/%04d' % (ud, i), 'rb').read())

    summary(name, size, time.clock() - start)
    shutil.rmtree(ud)

def main():
    IPs = get_IPs()
    print len(IPs), 'IPs available.'
    for ip in IPs:
        adapter = requests_toolbelt.adapters.SourceAddressAdapter(ip)
        session = requests.Session()
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        sessions_queue.put(session)

    while True:
        threading.Thread(target=download, args=(raw_input(),)).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sessions_queue = Queue.Queue()
    KB = 1024
    MB = 1024*KB
    # TODO: optimal size?
    CHUNK_SIZE = 100*KB
    MAX_RETRIES = 2
    main()
```

I am using it with about 100 IP addresses on my Ethernet -- each with about 100 KB/s speed. What'd be optimal configuration? (numbers of threads, chunk size)

Comment: You can experiment with the number of threads. I did something similar with 500 files and 40 threads in about 5 seconds, but found that with more than 8 or so threads the total time doesn't decrease. Your ISP may be a factor.

Comment: It depends on your CPU and memory speed, on your network (ethernet speed, eventual switches or routers, interface cards, network contention...). Just test it with different parameters and choose the one that best fits.